# Struts2 checkbox saving to other bean

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2

I have a problem with saving checkbox value into some bean. With other stuff like text etc all is ok. Also I don't have any problems if I save checkbox value to MyAction class.
Problem only appears when I try to do so with some bean in my class.

example jsp:

```
<s:form>
<s:checkbox name="myBean.flag"/>
<s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

======

example java code:

```
public class MyAction extends Action {
private MyBean myBean;

public MyBean getMyBean(){
     if(myBean == null){myBean = new MyBean();}return myBean;}
}

public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean){this.myBean = myBean;}

}
```

...

```
public class MyBean {
private boolean flag;

public MyBean isFlag(){return flag;}

public void setFlag(boolean flag){this.flag = flag;}
}
```

======

P.S. Seems that I have more less the same problem as this guy have:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/448207/Struts/Struts-Checkbox-set-value-back

Comment: BTW, `myBean.aFlag` should be `myBean.flag`

Comment: 2). It was just a typo in this topic.

Comment: 1). I can't save checkbox value into some bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct `aFlag` to `flag` and add `value` of the `checkbox` in:

```
<s:checkbox name="myBean.aFlag"/>
```

to:

```
<s:checkbox name="flag" value="flag" label="My CheckBox"/>
```

But in your `MyAction` class code just edit:

```
boolean flag;

public boolean isFlag() {
     if(myBean == null) {
         myBean = new MyBean();
     } 
     return myBean.getFlag();
}

public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
      this.myBean.setFlag(flag); 
      this.flag = flag;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't.

It was just a typo in this topic, not in my real code. with aFlag and flag. And no, it didn't work, because there's no such attribute "property" for struts2 checkbox tag.

Comment: I'm using such kind of workaround too. But it seems like workarounding s2's bugs :)

Comment: @hades Maybe but it seems to do the job :D and this is your Answer ;-)